# How to calculate the age from a given date?

Tags: php, html

In my registration form I have date picker for the date of birth. When I select the date, the age should automatically be calculated displayed.

Comment: Show what have you tried to get helped..

Comment: show your tried code?

Comment: To get proper answers it is important to ask good questions. How to do that is [described in the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also please note that the people on Stack Overflow don't do the work for you. You should at least provide what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function for calculating the age:

```
    function get_age($birth_date) {
      return floor((time() - strtotime($birth_date)) / 31556926);
    }
    echo get_age('12/12/1993');
```

The function is calculating the age gap between the current Unix timestamp (`time()`) and the birthdate timestamp in years. (31,556,926 are seconds in a year.)

Comment: @GuruKumar: we accepted your QUESTION....now you accept the answer :p

Comment: Don't shout @Vandana Pareek. Its the O/P's decision to mark which one is the correct answer.And there is no need to force the O/P to accept your answer.

Comment: @Vandana Pareek :I accept the answer Code is working , thanks :) :)

Comment: calm down and thank you so much for the generous advice @unnamed...

Comment: @GuruKumar To accept an answer you need to click the check besides it. You may also upvote answers, which helped solving your problem. There's also an [article in the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) describing this in more detail.

Comment: @VandanaPareek You should explain a bit what the code actually does.

Comment: @SebastianZartner: Yupp hv a look :)

Comment: Looks better, but maybe also explain what that magic number means.

Comment: @SebastianZartner: okayyyy...done.

Answer (score 0):

For my previous project, i am used the JQuery created the date-picker and get the user selected date to convert into time stamp format with also time stamp date for current date to calculate the different and get the user age.

[Link of documentation for date() in php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)